# PhoneGap is not loading correct icons/splash screens for iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, icons, sencha-touch

I'm building a Sencha Touch + PhoneGap app for android and iOS (iPhone & iPad). I'm having major issues with PhoneGap choosing the correct icons and splash screens to display for the correct devices.

**For example:** 
Android loads the correct main icon, however, it will load a splash screen that is very pixelated (I believe its loading one for the 320x460 iphone screen.)

iOS on both iPhone and iPad are showing the android icon and not loading the correct splash screens.

I'm really stuck on this and would appreciate any input on the matter, thanks in advance!

My code for config.xml is below:

```
    <icon src="res/icons/icon.png" />

    <icon src="res/icons/icon-blackberry-92.png" default="true" />
    <icon src="res/icons/icon-blackberry-92-hover.png" hover="true" />

    <icon src="res/icons/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/> 
    <icon src="res/icons/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/> 
    <icon src="res/icons/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/> 

    <icon src="res/icons/icon-android-36.png" width="36" height="36"/> 
    <icon src="res/icons/icon-android-48.png" width="48" height="48"/> 
    <icon src="res/icons/icon-android-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>

    <gap:splash src="res/splash/Default@2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/splash/Default.png" width="320" height="460" />
    <gap:splash src="res/splash/splash-screen-ios-ipad.png" width="786" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/splash/splash-screen-400x800.png" width="400" height="800" />

    <gap:splash src="res/splash/Default.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the launch image file (UILaunchImageFile) property in your application's info.plist:

For example, if you set the value for the key UILaunchImageFile~ipad to iPad, your file names should be iPad-Portrait.png and iPad-Landscape.png. You could similarly change it for the iPhone, or use the default (Default.png) for iPhone.

This is defined in [Information Property List Files.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW9)

Comment: Just to clarify, we are using PhoneGap BUILD (their cloud based multi OS compiler) build.phonegap.com.

Answer (score 0):

In the newest Phonegap Xcode build, you can drag and drop the images you want to use as splashscreens or icons into the GUI area in XCode under Targets/Summary. That should allow you to add those in directly. What version of Xcode are you using ?? I can add in more specific details if I know what version it is.